# Time complexity of this code (from Cracking the Coding Interview "Group Anagrams")

Tags: big-o

The author claims the following code to be O(n * log(n)). This seems to imply that the Comparator is doing constant-time work, but there's a sort embedded in the Comparator's compare() function. Doesn't this increase the time complexity?

```
class AnagramComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  public String sortChars(String s) {
    char[] content = s.toCharArray();
    Array.sort(content);
    return new String(content);
  }

  public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    return sortChars(s1).compareTo(sortChars(s2));
  }
}

Arrays.sort(array, new AnagramComparator());
```

Comment: The embedded sort call's time complexity depends on the lengths of the strings, not the *number* of strings (`n`). The author has probably assumed this to be small.

Comment: So, if we call the size of the biggest string `s`, and assume `s << n`, we can disregard the embedded sort's time complexity of `O(n * s * log(s))` because `O(n * log(n))` is the dominant term?

Comment: Are you referring to line 4? If so, since we are sorting an array of size `s`, isn't that an `O(s * log(s))` operation each time?

Comment: I meant that `O(n * log(n) * s * log(s)) = O(n * s * log(n))`, not `O(n * s * log(s))`.